how to define a created_at read-only columns that is automatically filled with the creation date of the record
I want to define a created_at date column in drizzle
The column is ready only, so the type inferred should for this field as optional (Date | undefined) for creation.
I tried with this:
export const user = pgTable('user', {
    id: text('id').primaryKey(),
    age: integer('age'),
    [...]
    created: timestamp('created', { withTimezone: true, mode: 'date' })
        .default(sql`now()`)
});

export type User = typeof user.$inferSelect;

but the inferred type is:
type User = {
    id: string;
    age: number | null;
    [...]
    created: Date; // this should be created?: Date
}

How can I achieve such a thing

Why should the created field be optional (Date|undefined) if is has always a default value? Does the default value not imply that it will always have a value, meaning that the type is correct the way it is?
